# PHP: Can I get the line where my method has been called inside my class?

Tags: php

Say I have MyClass.php

```
class MyClass
{
    public static function myMethod()
    {
        // Here I want to know the line (and file) where my method has been called
    }
}
```

And SomeOtherFile.php

```
// other code ...

MyClass::myMethod();

// other code ...
```

So, is there a way to get the line from SomeOtherFile, where myMethod() has been called directly in myMethod? I mean, without passing the line as parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`debug_backtrace()` should do the job:

```
class MyClass
{
    public static function myMethod()
    {
        var_dump(debug_backtrace());
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's even more than I needed. Great function.